# Set brightness/contrast in video capture using Android Camera2

Tags: android, video, video-capture, android-camera2

I made a video capture app with Camera2 API by following [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) guide,

Is there a provision to change brightness/contrast/exposure settings of the video programatically? I'm trying to capture some low-lit video footage, and I wish to increase the exposure.

The documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) seems to apply only for still pictures.

Any such way for video capture, using **Camera2** API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the configuration that you need should be in [`CaptureRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html), for example for brightness [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION).

So, to implement it with the guide you follow, it's in the part 5. of the main steps listed in the readme, you need to use the `CaptureRequest.Builder` created [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L484) to set all the configuration that you want, with [`CaptureRequest.Builder#set(Key<T> key, T value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder.html#set(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest.Key%3CT%3E,%20T)) and the fields from [`CaptureRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html) !

Comment: Wich part ? Everything is linked in the answer

Comment: What is the key, value here to pass? I tried `captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, 6);` but no effect in brightness.. :( See my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47196243/2462531)