# Android Camera2 API set custom Brightness, Contrast, Gamma

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

Since **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35354363/3226984)** hasn't clear answer, and stackoverflow hasn't questions / answers about Camera 2 API Gamma, I ask for solution to modify Brightness, Contrast and Gamma using [Android Camera 2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html).
My code to get **[range](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE)** and **[step](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_STEP)**:

```
Rational controlAECompensationStep = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_STEP);
if (controlAECompensationStep != null) {
    compensationStep = controlAECompensationStep.doubleValue();
}

Range<Integer> controlAECompensationRange = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE);
if (controlAECompensationRange != null) {
    minCompensationRange = controlAECompensationRange.getLower();
    maxCompensationRange = controlAECompensationRange.getUpper();
}
```

My method to set **Brightness in percents**:

```
public void setBrightness(int value) {
    int brightness = (int) (minCompensationRange + (maxCompensationRange - minCompensationRange) * (value / 100f));
    previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, brightness);
    applySettings();
}
private void applySettings() {
    try {
        captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this approach doesn't work correctly. Image becomes [green](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xelc71a72qkoipp/20170321_095250.png?dl=0), like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35439159/3226984).

---

I described all what I found in **[documentation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19BJNgWeAfy1BvgDOF_Kp8WyjMkvSwSpNDvHanK7jE2s)**.

Comment: You can try Spectaculum, it works with Camera2 API:

https://github.com/protyposis/Spectaculum?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4529

Comment: @UmairAdil thank you for response. but it isn't what I actually want.

Comment: @VladimirKulyk I have gone through and installed the apk on Nexus 5x device and B+, B- works fine. No green color?

Comment: @AnuragSingh ok :D looks like I set `AutoWhiteBalance` to `false` if changing B, G or C manually. It makes my preview green.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. If you need to update apk, please do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My mistake was in changing [Auto White Balance Mode(AWB)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AWB_MODE) to [CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF) before modifying Brightness(B), Gamma(G) or Contrast(C).
Do not set `OFF` mode for `AWB`, use `AUTO` or other from possible modes.

---

**get current B in percents**

```
public int getBrightnessValue() {
    int absBRange = maxCompensationRange - minCompensationRange;
    int value = getValue(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION);
    return 100 * (value - minCompensationRange) / absBRange;
}
```

---

**set B in percents**

```
public void setBrightness(int value) {
    int brightness = (int) (minCompensationRange + (maxCompensationRange - minCompensationRange) * (value / 100f));
    previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, brightness);
    applySettings();
 }
```

---

**set C in percents**

```
//set def channels (used for contrast)
TonemapCurve tc = previewRequestBuilder.get(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_CURVE);
if (tc != null) {
    channels = new float[3][];
    for (int chanel = TonemapCurve.CHANNEL_RED; chanel <= TonemapCurve.CHANNEL_BLUE; chanel++) {
        float[] array = new float[tc.getPointCount(chanel) * 2];
        tc.copyColorCurve(chanel, array, 0);
        channels[chanel] = array;
    }
}
```

```
public void setContrast(int value) {
    final int minContrast = 0;
    final int maxContrast = 1;

    if (channels == null || value > 100 || value < 0) {
        return;
    }

    float contrast = minContrast + (maxContrast - minContrast) * (value / 100f);

    float[][] newValues = new float[3][];
    for (int chanel = TonemapCurve.CHANNEL_RED; chanel <= TonemapCurve.CHANNEL_BLUE; chanel++) {
        float[] array = new float [channels[chanel].length];
        System.arraycopy(channels[chanel], 0, array, 0, array.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] *= contrast;
        }
        newValues[chanel] = array;
    }
    TonemapCurve tc = new TonemapCurve(newValues[TonemapCurve.CHANNEL_RED], newValues[TonemapCurve.CHANNEL_GREEN], newValues[TonemapCurve.CHANNEL_BLUE]);
    previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE, CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE_CONTRAST_CURVE);
    previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_CURVE, tc);
    applySettings();
}
```

---

```
private void applySettings() {
    captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
}
```

---

**G** is still in progress.

---

*Code examples above may be not 100% correct, if you have better solutions or found a bug, please let me know* ;)

Comment: Here I am unable to find `getValue`  @`getValue(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION);` ?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda `private CaptureRequest.Builder previewRequestBuilder;` `Integer brightness = previewRequestBuilder.get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION);`

Comment: how to get channels array for contrast

Comment: @SumitMarwha look at `//set def channels (used for contrast)` comment and code bellow.

Comment: TonemapCurve tc = previewRequestBuilder.get(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_CURVE); --Getting null in resilt

Comment: Volodymyr good code but be aware that posts can move around on stack.  You should post your answer and then comment the link to it.  It's not "below" anymore.  Like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42925286/9008140

Comment: previewRequestBuilder.get(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_CURVE) return null, do u know why?