# android cameraX API brightness issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using CameraX Api in my app and I'm faced with a problem with "Auto-Brightness Adjustment". Actually, In some devices, it works well but in others, camera preview is very dark compared to the original camera.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196243/android-camera2-increase-brightness) somebody had the same issue but with Camera2 API.
It is worth mention that when I tested [google camera sample apps](https://github.com/android/camera-samples) (Camera2BasicJava and CameraXBasic), I figured out that they had the same problem too.
I would be appreciated if you could help me with this.

Comment: Any update about this? I need help!

Comment: No. Nothing actually. @user3154785

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an library issue. This was already observed on the camera 2 api.
I opened an bug on the official bug tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148045396